# What is the difference between -Pprod command and spring.active.profile=prod?

Tags: maven, spring-boot

When i execute this using command line,

**mvnw clean install spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true**

Project run properly

But when i try same thing using -Pprod command it gives an error
(Run properly but main page can't be displayed),

**mvnw clean install spring-boot:run -Pprod -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true**

Currently i have three profile dev,test and prod.

I want to know, what is the difference between both of them?

Please give me some idea regarding -Pprod command.

Answer (score 2):

`-Pprod` is a property for the Maven call and activates the Maven profile with the name `prod`, `spring.profiles.active=prod` activates the Spring profile. They are not the same, so it depends where you have configured the 3 profiles (i guess you have configured them as Spring profiles, so the Spring property is the one that you have to use). It is possible though to configure Maven profiles in a way, so that also a Spring profile is activated in that run (basically in the Maven profile you would set the Spring profiles property to the value). You can find more about this [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). Short example:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>prod</id>
    <properties>
      <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: First of all thanks @dunni to replay this question. I tried this way(<profiles>) also but it not work

Comment: My project run successfully without any error, But when i try open it using the URL it display black page. It can't give any kind of error, So that i can't understand properly where is the actual issue?